# Video on "Empty Image" doesnt show in Render?

Tags: rendering, image, video

I added in different random videos (behold first screenshot) on an Empty Image Plane to see if it was the video or its position but the rendered view doesnt show my video even though it runs fine in the program. what am i missing?
any help much appreaciated! 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, empties as images will not render, just like images as background. They are used on the viewport as reference only.

To have renderable objects use images as planes instead.